# Reading non tabular html pages and writing into sql tables

Tags: php, python, sql, regex, pandas

I wanted to create a sql database containing table in which one column is for question , 4 columns are for options and one is for right answer (there may be extra column containing topic name as well ) and i want to enter a lot of questions into this table but the problem is the questions i am getting are in the form of html pages that are not in table form . They are in this form [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUhaf.png) . So how do i do it?
[The sample html page](http://www.questionpapers.net.in/question_papers/physics/kinetic_theory_of_gases_1.html)

Comment: I don't know Python, but if you view the HTML table as a DOM component, then figuring out how to iterate it to generate SQL rows becomes much easier.

Comment: What do you mean by " the questions I am getting are in the form of HTML pages"? Do you need to scrape or obtain these pages first? Why do you have tagged your question as PHP and Python? I feel your question is too broad.

Comment: Yeah i have to obtain those pages first . I have tagged php and python coz i think it could be done by using anyone of those ..i am basically interested in script that will enter the data into tabular format fetching data from source that are in non tabular format

Answer (score 0):

Well, You can maintain it in one single table as there are only four answer options but that is not the effective way to do it. As Database Design logic dictates that you have to Normalize the Database tables in order to maintain consistency. The best approach for this, as per database design, is to have 3 tables. One for holding the questions, the second for holding the options and the third for the right answers (You can merge the right answer with the first if you like).

When you want to get the answer options then you can get them using JOINs. The main advantage of this approach is its very expendable i.e., if, in the future, your number of options and number of correct answer changes, then they can be easily maintained.

I have prepared a sample Db structure on how you can achieve this. You can find it [Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f17b7e/1). The code that I have shared is a sample one. Please let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Hope this helps.